# Difference between JMX and PMI

Tags: websphere, java

I'm not a websphere admin but I understand the basics of JMX and PMI. I'm wondering what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMX is an interface which can provide wide range of actions where one of them is gathering PMI metrics from PerfMBean

Oracle defines JMX as follows:

> To make it short, JMX is a technology that lets you implement
>   management interfaces for Java applications.
>
> A management interface, as defined by JMX, is composed of named
>   objects - called MBeans (Management Beans). MBeans are registered with
>   a name (an ObjectName) in an MBeanServer. To manage (a) resource(s) in
>   your application, you will write an MBean that defines its management
>   interface, and then register that MBean in your MBeanServer.